Understanding proof for existence of eigenvalues
I am studying LADR by Sheldon Axler. I do not exactly understand one of the steps in the proof for theorem:

Thm: Every operator on a finite-dimensional nonzero complex vector space has an
eigenvalue.
Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space of dimension $n > 0$ and $T \in \mathscr{L}(V)$. Choose $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$. Then
$$
v, Tv, T^2v, \dots, T^nv
$$
is not linearly independent, because $V$ has dimension $n$ and this list has length $n+1$. Hence some linear combination (with not all the coefficients equal to $0$) of the vectors above equals $0$. Thus there exists a nonconstant polynomial $p$ of smallest degree such that $p(T)v = 0$.
By the first version of the fundamental theorem of algebra (see 4.12), there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $p(\lambda) = 0$. Hence there exists a polynomial $q \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $p(z) = (z - \lambda)\,q(z)$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (see 4.6). This implies (using 5.17) that
$$
0 = p(T)v = (T - \lambda I)\bigl(q(T)v\bigr).
$$
Because $q$ has smaller degree than $p$, we know that $q(T)v \neq 0$. Thus the equation above implies that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $q(T)v$.

Why are we assuming $q(T)v \neq 0$? Can't the overall polynomial have more roots?

The polynomial $p$ is chosen as the nonconstant polynomial of smallest degree such that $p(T)v = 0$. By construction, $\deg(q) = \deg(p) - 1$, so it must be the case that $q(T)v \neq 0$, lest it violate the minimality of the degree of $p$.

Thanks a lot! I missed that part. In general I understood why theorem must be true "intuitively" I also checked older edition of the book which had slightly different proof to convince myself. But now it is clear to me with this edition of the proof.
